# Should one use an indefinite article after 'kind of'?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

If the noun after *kind of* is singular, do we use an indefinite article or not?
For example,

> - That kind of an answer is teasing.
> - That kind of answer is teasing.

Which is correct?

Comment: Have you tried asking on [ell.se] ?

Comment: I think the article comes in with pure noun phrases but not with gerund-like ones. *I can't stand that kind of **a** noise* vs. *I can't stand that kind of noise-making.*

Comment: @Kris - perhaps it's AmE, but I disagree. *That kind of attitude will get you nowhere.* *That kind of man is trouble.* *That kind of fabric itches.* *That kind of error is preventable*.

Comment: @medica I would use an article in *every* one of those, in formal writing, AmE or not.

Comment: @Kris - Ngrams shows *this kind of error* is 371X more common than *this kind of an error*, so you are in a small minority.

Comment: @medica Do not go by nGrams alone. And my comment is not a canonical answer.

Comment: @Kris my impression is that the article here is far more extensively used in America than in Britain, where it tends to be retained only for emphasis or very deliberate statements.

Comment: I side with @medica. _that_ takes the place of _an_ as the article and as you can only have one article _that_ is it. _that answer_, not _that an answer_. Thus _that kind of answer_. As an native AmE speaker, _that kind of an answer_ sounds unnatural to my ear where as _that kind of answer_ doesn't.

Comment: @WS2 - we don't use the article in AmE. How then can we use it far more extensively than in Britain? What evidence do you have for the use of an article in this phrasing in America?

Comment: @medica I honestly don't know, and I trust what you say. But 'that kind of a thing' just sounds American to me. Clearly someone somewhere is saying it because people, including the OP, are hearing it. And it aint me what's saying it!

Comment: @DanD. Incidentally, *a native*, not *an*; *whereas*, not *where as*

Comment: @DanD. This *that* has nothing to do with that *that* -- think again.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct and grammatical. Personally I think I would usually leave out the article, but maybe not always.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a slight difference - or at least slight in terms of habits of usage. But "kind of" tends as a phrase to gravitate towards entities that actually exist and that are readily identifiable, whereas "kind of a" tends towards the hypothetical.

"That **kind of** car doesn't suit my purposes," says someone, speaking of a particular make and model.

"What **kind of a** car would it be that allowed passengers to stand?", says someone else, speaking of a car that might exist, but probably doesn't.

As I say, the difference is slight, and both forms are continually invading each other's territory, but I do think that there is a particular flavour to "kind of a" that tends towards the hypothetical.